# Timer Class issues in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer, addeventlistener

I started studying ActionScript 3 and I'm developing some projects to exercise.
I'm stuck on a problem:
The first keyframe reproduces a video, after that, the program should skip to keyframe 2. So i've implemented a Timer with the length of the video. All fine until I decided to add a event listener to skip the video just pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key. It works but the counter doesn't stop! Infact, after some seconds that I'm in the keyframe 2 (when timer is finished) the keyframe 2 reloads. Here is the code I wrote:

```
stop();
var count_to_17:Timer = new Timer(17000, 1);

count_to_17.start();
count_to_17.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, change_frame);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,change_frame2);

function change_frame(evento:TimerEvent):void{
    count_to_17.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, change_frame);
    gotoAndPlay(2);
}

function change_frame2(evento:KeyboardEvent):void{
    if(evento.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER){
    count_to_17.stop();
    count_to_17.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, change_frame);
    gotoAndPlay(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you receiving any errors?  Also, did you mean `gotoAndStop` instead of `gotoAndPlay`?

Comment: there is a stop(); in the frame 2, so its the same i think... and I don't receive any error... its a semantic error, sintax is ok...

Answer (score 0):

change both gotoAndPlay to gotoAndStop, that should work.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, you don't need Timer Class.

I'm Assuming you have a Movie clip of 17 seconds on frame one, and another movieclip on frame two.Increasing number of empty Frames after second frame will do the Trick,

OR

**put `stop();`** again in your **second keyFrame.**

and only this much of code is required.

For first frame:

```
stop();

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,change_frame2);

function change_frame2(evento:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (evento.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER)
    {
        nextFrame();
    }
```

If whatever I understood is Right,

Comment: In case I'm wrong and you want to stick to your code, Just add stop();
in your second key frame.